# Remove empty rows from a csv file created in Excel

Tags: r, excel, csv, dataframe

I have a dataframe imported from an excel csv. This works so far, however the csv saves always 49'999 rows, even though there are only roughly 10'000 rows of data. The rest of the rows is all empty.

How can I select now only that part of the data frame containing at least one column with data? with one row I managed to do it:

```
 MyDF[length(MyDF[MyDF!=""])>0]
```

But how can I do that for a whole dataframe? I would like to assign that "sub-data frame" to a new data frame.

**EDIT Example Data:**

Very simple example:

```
data<-matrix(c(1,2,1,NA,NA,NA),nrow=3,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    1   NA
[3,]   NA   NA

data2<-data[sum(!is.na(test))>0,]
```

doesn't subset..but why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When reading data like this created in Excel, you have to take care of the `NA` and the `""`, depending if the column is recognized as numeric or as character/factor by R. Alternatively, you can add the option `na.strings = c("NA", "")` when reading your data, so all the blanks will be NA and you don't need to care of the `""`.

```
newdata = data[!apply(is.na(data) | data == "", 1, all), ]
```

the `!apply(is.na(data) | data == "", 1, all)` inside will give you TRUE for the rows with at least one column with data. For the rest is FALSE, so they are not taken.

Also, when creating a csv file from Excel, you can try to remove all the columns to the right of your data, because it can also artificially create ghost data columns. This works also to remove the blank rows at the bottom.

Comment: doesn't complete cases only look for rows that are complete? But I don't want that, since some columns are finished earlier than others. I want rows where at least and only at least! one column contains data. As soon as no column contains data anymore the file is finished.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your thorough reply. Somehow it doesn't subset it at all. I don't know why, even though these rows are completely empty (and all characters) I've tried it with your advice na.strings = c("NA","") and then with this: data2<-data[sum(!is.na(data))>0,], but still no subset is created

Comment: Can you add an example of your data? You can choose 10 lines of "good" rows and 10 of "bad" row, and then paste the result of dput(DF).

Comment: See the result of sum(!is.na(data))>0 and you'll answer yourself. Still don't understand why my answer if not working for you, it works with your example.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, your function works fine :-) Thx a lot for your efforts!